# class object and property variation in dart

Tags: flutter, class, dart, constructor, getter-setter

so i recently started learning dart and I've found something kinda interesting.

why do we use constructors and getters/setters when we can achieve same results without them? (atleast when used for basic things).

```
class v1{
  var name;
  int age;
  
  v1(this.name, this.age);
  
  info(){
    print("my name is $name and i am $age");
  }
}

class v2{
  var name = "bash";
  int age = 100;
  
  info(){
    print("my name is $name and i am $age");
  }
}

class v3{
  var namee;
  int agee;
  
  String get name => namee;
  int get age => agee;
  
  set name(String name) => this.namee = name;
  set age(int age) => this.agee = age;
  
  info(){
    print("my name is $name and i am $age");
  }
}


void main(){
  var x = v1("bash", 100);
  x.info(); //my name is bash am i am 100
  
  var z = v2();
  var Z = v2();
  Z.name = "vert";
  Z.age = 20;
  z.info(); //my name is bash and i am 100
  Z.info(); //my name is vert and i am 100
  
  var y = v3();
  y.name = "rizz";
  y.age = 40;
  y.info(); //my name is rizz and i am 40
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more correct version of your class:

```dart
class User {
  final bool _isMale;
  String _name;
  int _age;

  User(this._isMale, this._name, this._age);

  bool isMale => _isMale;
  String get name => _name;
  int get age => _age;

  set name(String name) {
    // Sometimes you may want to update other properties here.
    // For example:
    // _isUpdated = true;
    _name = name;
  }

  set age(int age) {
    _age = age;
  }

  void info() {
    print("my name is $name and i am $age");
  }
}
```

Constructors are useful when you want to assign initial values to the class fields. They are essential if you need to assign `final` fields, as they are assignable only on class initialization (see `_isMale` field).

Setters are useful when you want to update other fields along with the field that's being modified.

Getters protect the internal state from being modified outside. In this example, nobody can change `_isMale` field.

Comment: thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use getters and setters unless you have to.

You use getters and setters if you need to store the data in a private field, or if you want to modify it when saving or returning the value.

```dart
class Abc {
    String _field;
    String _otherField;

    String anotherField; // No getters and setters required for this.

    String get field => _field;
    set field(String field) => _field = field;

    String get otherField => "The value of otherField is: " + _otherField;
    set otherField(String otherField) => _otherField = "[String] " + otherField;
}
```

As for constructors, you use them to initialize the object with custom values. When you need to work with immutable objects (which use `final` variables), you'll have to use constructors to set their initial value. You can also modify the incoming value according to your need before storing it,

```dart
class Def {
    final field; // Dart generates getters for this field, but it's value can't be modified once the object is instantiated.
    final _otherField; // No getters for this.
    Def(String field, String otherField) {
        this.field = "[String] $field"
        this._otherField = "[String] $otherField"
    }

    String describeMe() {
        return "[Def]: field: $field, _otherField: $_otherField"
    }
}
```

Comment: I now see the bigger picture, thanks, you won't find infos like this in most tutorials .

Comment: Always happy to help!